# How to open file from internal storage in specific viewer?

Tags: android

I want to open File which is in `InternalStorage`

I created **Documents** directory under **data/data/mypackage/files** path .

Now I want to **Open a file in some external application like PDF viewer or text viewer.**

I already checked, the file exists but when I am opening file in specific viewer like PDF viewer,

it display Toast-  **"Can not display PDF"**.

I am using below code to open file in the specific viewer.

```
File file=new File(context.getFilesDir()+"/Documents/"+fileInfo.getFilename()+"."+fileInfo.getFiletype());
if (file.exists()){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Chooser will open for select PDF viewer.

> How to Open PDF or Text File from internal Storage
>   (data/data/com..somepackagename/files)?

Comment: try this   intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");

Comment: Use `FileProvider`. As the one answer points out, other apps cannot access `getFilesDir()` of your app. Plus `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ devices, as `Uri` values built that way are banned from use in `Intents`.

Answer (score 1):

Third party apps cant access your package folder, if you want to open that file third party apps , move that file into shared folder